# Accept Infinity as an Integer argument

Tags: syntax

I have the following function, albeit contrived:

```
Foo[x_Integer] :=
  Module[{i},
   i = 1;
   While[i <= x && i <= 10, i++];
   i - 1
   ];
```

I am looking for the following

```
Foo[1] = 1
.
.
.
Foo[10] = 10
Foo[11] = 10
Foo[Infinity] = 10
```

However `Foo[Infinity]` returns `Foo[\[Infinity]]` and not `10` .

Is there an something that I can do, short of: `Foo[Infinity] = 10;` to get `Foo[Infinity]` to return `10` ?  The problem is `i <= 10` is static in my contrived example, but will be dynamic in practice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) to have the pattern accept either an integer or `Infinity` as an argument, like so:

```
Pillsy`Foo[x : (_Integer | Infinity)] :=
 Module[{limit = Min[x, 10], i = 1},
  While[i <= limit, ++i];
  i - 1]
```

It helps that Mathematica functions like `Min` and `Max` usually do the right thing with `Infinity` as an argument.